# php conditional statement not working in magento

Tags: php, magento

So I have an e-newsletter popup on my website so users can stay in contact and up to date with our happenings. I only want the popup to appear on the homepage and i've put together a simple shorthand conditional statement like so:

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getPageId() == '2' && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms') : ?>    

<div id="newsletter_sign_up" style="display:none;" >

<div style="padding:20px;" >
<form action="<?php echo($this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new')) ?>" method="post" >
  <div class="fieldset">

    <h1 style="color: #28ced7; text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 28px;">verbiage goes here</h1>

    <h2 class="legend" style="text-align:left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">verbiage goes here</h2>
    <!--end-->
    <ul class="form-list">
      <li class="fields">
        <div class="customer-name">
          <div class="field name-firstname">
            <label class="required" for="firstname" style="text-align:left;"><em>*</em>First Name</label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="255" title="First Name" value="" name="firstname" id="firstname" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field name-lastname">
            <label class="required" for="lastname" style="text-align:left;"><em>*</em>Last Name</label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="255" title="Last Name" value="" name="lastname" id="lastname" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="required" for="email_address"  style="text-align:left;"><em>*</em>Email Address</label>
        <div class="input-box">

          <input type="text" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" title="Email Address" value="" id="email_address" name="email" autocomplete="off"/>

      <input class="pop_newsletter_source" name="source" type="hidden" value="3" />

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-set form-buttons">
    <button onclick="pop_newsletter.submit(); return false;" title="Submit" class="button" type="submit" autocomplete="off" style="position: relative; right: 140px;"><span><span>Submit</span></span></button>
  </div>
  <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>

  <h2 style="text-align: left; font-size: 10px;">Email Privacy Statement:</h2>
  <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; text-align: left;">more verbiage</p>
  <!--//end-->
</form>
</div>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I've checked to verify that the page id is 2.

```
<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getPageId()); echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

I can't figure out why it breaks... am i missing something blatantly obvious? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly `'breaks'`? Are you saying that the page doesn't load anymore? Or the form just never appears? Also, even though you're using loosey-comparisons, I would recommend making it `2` as opposed to `'2`' given that you're comparing int-types anyway, might as well be cohesive. :)

Comment: It loads on every page, sorry i had to flush the cache. It loads but it's loading on every page.

Comment: Ah you know what...I think that the `getRouteName()` is actually wrong. Can you dump that and verify it returns `cms` and not something like `page` or `proudct` or `catalog`?

Comment: ahhh.. you're on to something i think.. when i print_r i got a fatal error:  Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_App::getRouteName() in C:\inetpub\xampp\htdocs\public_html\app\design\frontend\enterprise\lsd\template\page\html\footer.phtml on line 245

Comment: Looks like that method actually belongs to `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front`

Comment: Can i use that method just like any other method?

Comment: I don't understand why i need that second condition anyway? But using just this method doesn't work either.  <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getPageId() == '2') : ?>

Comment: One more thing. If i var_dump: <?php echo "<pre>"; var_dump(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName()); echo "</pre>"; ?> it returns string(3) "cms".. so it should work correct?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, could you maybe provide some more help?